# How can i make auto login in Angular using interceptor?

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have an application with a login user via interceptor. When user login i recive token JWT and user data from DB. JWT i save in localstorage. All this information i saved also in variable session. When refresh page, i lost session. How can i make auto login after refresh page using interceptor? How will look like a code in my interceptor file? What can i add to function autologin() in auth.service.ts?

**auth-interceptor.service.ts**

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(this.getAuthorizedRequest(req)).pipe(
      catchError((err, caught) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
          this._auth.logout();
        }
        throw err;
      })
    );
  }
  getAuthorizedRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
    return req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this._auth.getToken(),
      },
    });
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
 private session = new BehaviorSubject<Session>({ token: '', user: {} });

  getToken() {
    const session = this.session.getValue();
    return session && session.token;
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    const session = this.session.getValue();
    return session && session.user;
  }

 login(credentials: any) {
    this._http.post(this.api_url, credentials).subscribe(
      (session: any) => {
        this.session.next(session);
      },
      (error) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          this.loginError = error.error;
          console.log(this.loginError);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  autoLogin() {
    const tokenFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (tokenFromLocalStorage) {
      console.log(tokenFromLocalStorage);
    }
  }
```

I tried looking for in stackoverflow, google, and youtube. I'm a junior front-end developer. I don't know how can i write this. I expecting ready to use code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your page is refreshed, the `session` BehaviorSubject is re-initialized with your initial value. Assuming that `autoLogin` is being called somewhere during app initialization (maybe inside your `AppComponent` or as part of [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER#usage-notes)), you could simply use code similar to the `login()` method:

```js
autoLogin() {
  const tokenFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (tokenFromLocalStorage) {
    console.log(tokenFromLocalStorage);
    this.session.next({token: tokenFromLocalStorage, user: {}})
  }
}
```

Then, whenever an HTTP request is made, the token will be ready to add to a header via your `this._auth.getToken()` method.

From your code example, I do not see the user data or JWT being stored in `localStorage` - successful logins only update the `session` BehaviorSubject. In order to read from `localStorage` between refreshes, that data should be set on successful login:

```js
login(credentials: any) {
  this._http.post(this.api_url, credentials).subscribe(
    (session: any) => {
      this.session.next(session);
      // I'm assuming that the returned `session` value is an object
      // with `user` and `token` keys
      localStorage.setItem('user', session.user);
      localStorage.setItem('token', session.token);
    },
  ...
}

autoLogin() {
  const tokenFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const userFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('user');
  if (tokenFromLocalStorage && userFromLocalStorage) {
    console.log(tokenFromLocalStorage);
    this.session.next({token: tokenFromLocalStorage, user: userFromLocalStorage})
  }
}
```